# How to check if the user is in trial or not?

Tags: woocommerce, subscription, hook-woocommerce, trial

I have an issue with woocommerce. I am new to woocommerce as well as wordpress, but need to check if the current user is in trial period or already renewed user.
I hope you would like to teach me kindly.

Currently I am using action hooks in woocommerce, `woocommerce_subscription_status_changed` exactly. This hook function does have parameter `$subscription`, which might be able to give me that info, I believe.

Is there a function like `wcs_is_in_trial`?

Thanks,
Alexis

Comment: What version of WooCommerce? And what version of Subcritions?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think the version must have been `3.1.1`.

Comment: Everything you need is on this page: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/

Comment: I can't find the correct way. I tried to use `<?php WC_Subscription::get_date( 'trial_end' ) ?>` and `$subs->get_date('trial_end')`. But nothing works.

Comment: Did you try: 
`$trial_end = WC_Subscription::get_date( 'trial_end');`

Comment: Yes, I did. The response was blank.

Comment: Are you sure there was a trial end date in the example you're pulling?

Comment: Yes, it has 3 days trial.

Comment: Did you try: $subscription->get_date( 'trial_end' );

Comment: Yes, I did. It just returns `0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151320/discussion-between-difster-and-alexis-richard).